# Recieving error message "expected identifier or ')' before '}' token" in Code Blocks IDE

Tags: c

I am recieving the error message from the title in this code below

```
int main()
{
  int day = 1;
  float penny = 0.01;
  while (day<32)
    printf("On Day %d you had %f dollars",day, penny);
    penny *=2;
    day++;

  }


    return 0;
```

Any and all help is appreciated. :D

Comment: You have mismatched curly braces.  You forgot the opening `{` for the `while` statement.

Comment: I'm sure Code Blocks has an autoformatter, use it! Also, please study the posting guidelines: If you had bothered to extract the required minimal example, you would have found the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing `{` after `while` and `}` after `return 0;`

```
int main()
{
  int day = 1;
  float penny = 0.01;
  while (day<32)
  {
     printf("On Day %d you had %f dollars",day, penny);
    penny *=2;
    day++;

  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing a `{` after `while (day<32)`.